# Tensorflow: how to create a local variable?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how local and global variables are different in tensorflow and what's the right way to initialize the variables.

According to the doc, `tf.local_variables_initializer`:

> Returns an Op that initializes all local variables.
>
> This is just a shortcut for variables_initializer(local_variables())

So the essential part is `tf.local_variables`. [The doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/local_variables):

> Local variables - per process variables, usually not saved/restored to checkpoint and used for temporary or intermediate values. For example, they can be used as counters for metrics computation or number of epochs this machine has read data.

It sounds logical, however, no matter how I tried, I couldn't make any variable local.

```
features = 2
hidden = 3

with tf.variable_scope('start'):
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, features], name='x')
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name='y')

with tf.variable_scope('linear'):
  W = tf.get_variable(name='W', shape=[features, hidden])
  b = tf.get_variable(name='b', shape=[hidden], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
  z = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

with tf.variable_scope('optimizer'):
  predict = tf.reduce_sum(z, axis=1)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - predict))
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

print(tf.local_variables())
```

The output is always an empty list. **How** and **should** I create local variables?

Answer (score 1):

A local variable is just a regular variable that's added to a "special" collection.

The collection is `tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES`.

You can pick any variable definition and just add the parameter `collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]` to add the variable to the specified collection list.

Comment: Thanks, I've found it at the same moment as you answered

Answer (score 1):

Think I found it. The magic addition to make a variable local is `collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]` in `tf.get_variable`. So this way `W` becomes are local variable:

```
W = tf.get_variable(name='W', shape=[features, hidden], collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
```

The documentation mentions one more possibility that also works:

```
q = tf.contrib.framework.local_variable(0.0, name='q')
```